# Delete rows based on date using VBA

Tags: vba, date, delete-row

Each month new data (from the previous month) is pasted over old data. The number of days each month changes due to nonwork days.

I tried clearing the cells and pasting data in blank cells, but this messes up the associated charts and graphs.

I want to delete entire rows with data before the last month, day 1.

[image: Example of data]

```vb
Sub ltest()

Dim d As Date
d = DateAdd("y", -1, Date)
LastMonth = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date))

Dim w As Long
For w = Sheet1.[a4].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
    Debug.Print Cells(w, "A").Value
    If CDate(Cells(w, "A")) < CDate(LastMonth) Then
        Cells(w, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next w

End Sub
```

Another attempt

```vb
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnDateRange()
Dim N As Long, I As Long
Dim lmon As Long

lmon = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, 1))
N = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For I = N To 1 Step -4
    If Sheet1.Cells(I, "A").Value < lmon Then
        Sheet1.Rows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example:

```
Sub DeleteOldDates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim previousM As Date
    Dim i, rowDate
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row in column A
    
    'Get current month and subtract 1 to get previous month
    previousM = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1)
        
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    rowDate = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If IsDate(rowDate) Then 'Check if cell contains a valid date
            If Year(rowDate) < Year(previousM) Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            ElseIf Month(rowDate) < Month(previousM) And Year(rowDate) = Year(previousM) Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```